# How can I remove commits from pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I had one commit in my pull-request. I then tried to change my e-mail and force-pushed the changes after doing so. Now I have lots of commits in my pull-request from other people. How can I remove these commits?

I have tried get reset, but the commits by the others are still shown in the pull-request.

Now my branch has all of the commits since the creation of the main repository in it.

Comment: Did you send the PR to the wrong branch ?

Comment: No, the PR branch is correct. I amended the PR by changing the e-mail.

Comment: Have you amended the commit (e.g. using `git rebase --interactive`) **after** the PR had already been merged and further commits made on top of it?

Comment: Maybe try to get a hold of what the actual situation is with a graphical tool like `gitk --all`.

Comment: I did a rewrite of the history as recommended here: https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private/

Comment: So you used `git filter-branch` as suggested [at the bottom of that page](https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private/#my-old-commits-still-have-my-old-email-address)?

Comment: Yes. @das-g     ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104112/discussion-between-das-g-and-barq).

Answer (score 6):

#### What probably happened

Probably, the upstream repository contained some (at least one) commit(s) by you (with your old / real email address) already before you submitted the current pull request. These commits have also been rewritten by the `filter-branch` script when you've followed GitHub's  [Changing author info](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/) recipe, and by extension all those commits' descendants, whether by you or not, have been rewritten, too.

That's why that page has a red warning box saying

> This action is destructive to your repository's history. If you're collaborating on a repository with others, it's considered bad practice to rewrite published history. You should only do this in an emergency.

and an blue info box elaborating

> **Note**: Running this script rewrites history for all repository collaborators. After completing these steps, any person with forks or clones must fetch the rewritten history and rebase any local changes into the rewritten history.

Your first commit in that repo was probably early in its history, which is why you now see almost the whole repo's history in your pull request.

#### What the current PR can cause

Would your modified pull request now be merged as-is, then the upstream repository would have most of its current commits twice: Once in their original variant, and once in the rewritten state by you. This would make for a very confusing repository history and at no benefit, as your old / real email address would still be in the history.

#### What you can (and should) do

Either withdraw your pull request, or

1. Find the upstream repo's commit your branch was originally based on.
2. Rebase your branch onto that commit. This should be possible without any merge conflicts.
3. Force-push your branch again, thereby updating the pull request again.

Now, your pull request should again only introduce the newly contributed commits and may (if otherwise fine and wanted) be accepted by the upstream repository owners.

Answer (score 2):

The PR will update if you update your branch. Do what you need to do in order to get the branch to look how you want it to look. You will probably have to reset it and force push your changes.

If it were me, I'd just cancel the PR and make a new one.